# first person character controller error

Tags: unity, first-person-shooter

I have opened new scene, deleted camera and imported first person character controller from Standard assets.
I placed plane on scene and put first person character controller on plane.

I got this error:

> Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/RigidbodyFirstPersonController.cs(3,27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CrossPlatformInput' does not exist in the namespace`UnityStandardAssets'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you import the CrossPlatformInput class along with the character controller from Standard Assets? By default it will pull everything in, but if you manually checked and unchecked some boxes then it's possible to miss a dependency. Check if it's in your assets folder. If so, you can also try closing Unity, deleting the Library folder, then re-opening the project. This forces a re-import and can sometimes fix cases when the editor is doing something inexplicable. ;)

Comment: I didn't check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the controller working properly, here is what you must import:

[image]